# Convert p12 APNS certificate to base64 string

Tags: node.js, openssl, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I want to send the .p12 file of APNS certificate to One Signal API, but I need first to convert the .p12 file to base64 string. How do I do that?
The API documentation is below:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-an-app

Comment: The script I am building is in Node.

Comment: The script that I have tried but did not work: 
new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/ios_push_certificate.p12", 'binary')).toString('base64')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/ios_push_certificate.p12")).toString('base64')
```

That is the correct script after all.

Answer (score 17):

If you're on a Mac you can use the base64 utility that comes with Mac.

```
base64 -i certificate.p12 -o outputfile
```

Comment: Is it possible to reverse this process?

Comment: I mean base64 to p12

Comment: @SPatel ```base64 --decode -i outputfile > certificate.p12```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the programming language you are using.

For example, here's how to do it in Ruby:

```
base64_encoded_p12 = Base64.encode64(File.read('/path/to/your/file.p12'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this on Linux

```
base64 file.p12
```

To write the base64 output to any file, you can use this

```
base64 file.p12 > output.base64
```

**Note:** This works for any files not only `.p12`